# Json not send via Unirest.post

Tags: java, json, unirest

I am trying to send a Json Object via a Unirest.post() inside a Test class, I got a working connection to the URL but getting exception that there was no Json object transmitted. Included the API call code below:

```
 try{
        String location = "http://localhost:" + port + "/check-person";
        System.out.println(location);
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse =
        Unirest.post("http://localhost:" + port + "/check-person")
        .body("{\"personName\": \"Darth Vader\"}")
        .asJson();
        assertEquals(403, jsonResponse.getStatus());
    } catch(UnirestException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: Try to set content type in header via Unirest.post("http://localhost:" + port + "/check-person").header("Content-Type", "application/json"). Include the exception logs so that others can figure out the error.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `Content-Type` in header as JSON. This will tell server that the body should be interpreted as JSON. Some common types as follows

> “application/json”, “application/xml”, “text/html”, “text/plain”

Add the content type header in UniRest request as in

```
try{
    String location = "http://localhost:" + port + "/check-person";
    System.out.println(location);
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse =
    Unirest.post("http://localhost:" + port + "/check-person")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .body("{\"personName\": \"Darth Vader\"}")
    .asJson();
    assertEquals(403, jsonResponse.getStatus());
} catch(UnirestException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e);
}
```